How to implement optional function argument with JavaScript
I need to implement some conditions with the help of matchPath from React Router.
I am creating a function for this.
import { matchPath } from "react-router";

export const MyKey = {
  Foo: "foo",
  Bar: "bar",
  Home: "",
} as const;

export const subPageMatch = (
  key: // the key can be `foo` or `bar`,
  path: string,
) => {
  return !!matchPath(path, {
    path: `/${key}/:subPage`,
  });
};

So I need to check on:
http://localhost:3000/foo/sub // should return `true`
http://localhost:3000/bar/sub // should return `true`
http://localhost:3000/test/sub // should return `false`
http://localhost:3000/foo/sub/anothersub // should also return `true`

How to create this function so I can add a conditional value as function argument?
And then be able to use it like:
const test = subPageMatch(---> here should evaluate to one of the values of the object MyKey, pathname);

So the first argument can be either "foo" || "bar".

Are you trying to pass the literal expression "foo" || "bar" or are you trying to limit the value of the first argument passed to subPageMatch to the string literals "foo" and "bar", i.e. one or the other? Are you just wanting to match either of "/foo/:subPage" or "/bar/:subPage"?

You can get the values of MyKey by first getting the keyof, and then index this to get the value.  Finally you can use Exclude to remove the '' option.
eg.
Exclude<typeof MyKey[keyof typeof MyKey], ''>,

TS Playground

Ok but then when using the function I like to have one const, like:
const test = subPageMatch("foo" || "bar", pathname); // this argument evaluates always to "foo"

@meez  That's because "foo" || "bar" equals foo   , I'm really not sure what your expecting here.   What I've done here is make it so you either provide foo or bar, if it's something else could you explain in more detail.

Maybe better to remove your answer then I will delete my question. Thanks
